Weird characters when downloading from browser

Whenever I'm trying to download or upload anything from browser (tested for Brave and Firefox), I get weird characters in the dialog box. My file explorer, and other applications are working fine, with Latin alphabets as default. What should I do to fix these dialog boxes?
Versions:
   Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 24.04.1
   Brave version: 1.73.104
   Firefox version: 133.0.3 (64-bit)
Installation steps:
   Brave:
    curl -fsS https://dl.brave.com/install.sh | sh
      install.sh uses sudo apt-get install -y brave-browser if apt-get is available
   Firefox:
    Don't remember installing, most likely came prepackaged with Ubuntu
      snap list does list firefox
       Confinement of firefox, from command snap info --verbose firefox
      confinement: strict

hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have added the versions as a part of the question. All the installations were done through standard methods (I think Firefox was pre-built, and Brave was installed through the method listed on its website). I started facing this error after upgrading ubuntu version from 22.04 to 24.04.

Additional info: Ubuntu upgrade was done via sudo do-release-upgrade

@guiverc I think I have added all the information that you asked for. Do let me know if I missed something.
